# How can I make this work? (Conditional typeclass instance)

Tags: haskell, type-families

I want to insert `trace` in Monad's `bind`, but it requires `Show` instance and makes many other instances to be modified.

I saw [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap#Solution_3_.28using_closed_type_families.29), and it seems the last one is the best solution. But there's no full example code, and I don't have enough knowledge yet about this language extension.

Could there be any better solution? And what's the problem of the below code?

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

data STrue = STrue
data SFalse = SFalse

type family ShowPred a where
  ShowPred Char = STrue
  ShowPred [Char] = STrue
  ShowPred a = SFalse

class Print' flag a where
  print' :: flag -> a -> b -> b
instance Show a => Print' STrue a where
  print' _ s v = traceShow s v
instance Print' SFalse a where
  print' _ _ = id

instance (ShowPred [t] ~ flag, Print' flag [t]) => Monad (Parser t) where
    return x     = P (\ts-> Success ts x)
    fail e       = P (\ts-> Failure ts e)
    (P f) >>= g  = P (continue . f)
      where
        continue (Success ts x) = let (P g') = g x in {- print' (undefined :: flag) ts $ -} g' ts
        continue (Committed r)  = Committed (continue r)
        continue (Failure ts e) = Failure ts e
```